# Geometry Nodes - "Panel" Option in Group Input. Unclear what it's for

Tags: geometry-nodes

In Geometry Nodes, when adding sockets to the node interface, the menu shows three options: Input, Output, and Panel:

[image]

What does the Panel option actually do? I can parent other Inputs and Outputs to it, but it doesn't seem to do anything aside from making it easier to read long Input / Output lists.
For me the naming implies that it allows you to group multiple Inputs together, to make them easier to read and sort in the Modifiers Menu, but it doesn't do that.

This is how I have it set up right now and how it looks in the Modifier:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the "Panel" option, you can combine additional inputs/outputs under a collapsible menu item.

However, this currently only works in the Node Editor and unfortunately not (yet) in the Modifier Panel.

Simply create additional inputs/outputs and move them to your panel using drag and drop.

A group created in this way will then look like this, for example:

[image]

Comment: Ah! I thought as much, but I wasn't sure. I completely forgot that I could also use this setup as a Node Group... so that's the last possibility that the "Panel" option had to actually do something.
Naturally, I forgot about that one. Thank you!

Comment: @dasfrodo I was just about to write my answer but I was too slow, as always :D As the answer says, unfortunately this is not (yet?) available in the modifier, but if you would built a custom node group, in your example you could keep those XYZ sockets just with the short name for the axis and leave the classification like "Random Min Scale", "Random Max Scale" etc. to the panel.

Comment: I think there is a very high chance the panels will be displayed in the modifier interface in the next Blender version. I don't see how the devs could let users use this feature and not let it reflect in the modifier interface for more than one version. :) Cross my fingers

Answer (score 3):

I was also confused and i hope it will be in the modifier be represended as well, but you can see it in the node group like this:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I checked the Modifier Panel but completely forgot that I could also use this setup as an individual Node Group. I really hope they add this to the Modifier Panel soon. Huge setups get incredibly overwhelming without it.